# truncate a table in a specific database

Tags: database, truncate

in phpmyadmin I have 30 databases. I would like to know which is the query to truncate the same table in a specific database.

I am currently using this query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE session;
```

But this is boring because I have to do the same in all 30 databases. Is there an option to apply this to the same table in all databases at once?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean all databases?  What type of databases are you using?  Are they on different servers?  Are they instances on the same server?  Do you actually mean schemas?  Please give more details even if it is boring

Comment: Haha, thank you, it's not boring to answer :)

All databases are on the same server, and access to them through the same phpmyadmin.

Imagine that my databases are called:

DDBB1
DDBB2
DDBB3
DDBB4
DDBB5
DDBB6

I would like to know if I could run such a query:

TRUNCATE TABLE session DDBB1;
TRUNCATE TABLE session DDBB2;
TRUNCATE TABLE session DDBB3;
TRUNCATE TABLE session DDBB4;
TRUNCATE TABLE session DDBB5;
TRUNCATE TABLE session DDBB6;

That is, a query where I indicate TRUNCATE + the name of the table + the name of the database

Thank you

Comment: There is no way to do that in any database system since the database does not hold the list of databases.  HOWEVER, there problably is way to do it in phpmyadmin since that system does know the list of all the databases.  That would a question for phpmyadmin support.